# dllhost.exe not available for debugging

Tags: asp-classic

I have the following problem:

`dllhost.exe` process is not available in the list of process to attach and break in order to debug asp script in `Microsoft Visual InterDev 6.0`

Answer (score 0):

Configure COM+ to Attach to the Dllhost.exe Process
Open the Component Services console.
Under Component Services, Computers, My Computer, COM+ Applications select the COM+ application package for your Web application.

NOTE: If you have set the Application Protection setting to Medium, then you will configure the following COM+ application package: 
IIS Out-Of-Process Pooled Applications

Open the Properties dialog box for your Web application.

On the Identity tab, select This user and then enter the account information that you will use for remotely debugging.
Attach to a Process in Visual InterDev
View the page that you want to debug in the browser.
Open Visual InterDev.
From the Debug menu, select Processes.
In the Processes section of the modal dialog box that appears, select the appropriate Machine, and then click Refresh. The list of available processes appears.
If you have set the Web application's Application Protection setting to High or Medium, attach to the Dllhost.exe process. Otherwise, attach to the Inetinfo.exe process.
Select the appropriate process, and then click Attach. The selected process appears in the Debugged Processes dialog box.
From the View menu, select Debug Windows, and then click Running Documents.
Open the document from the Running Documents window, and then set a breakpoint.
Refresh the page in the browser.